# Encoding issues when sending subject line to Outlook from IE

Tags: internet-explorer, encoding, outlook

we got a page with articles that you can mail your friends if you find it interesting.
So we got a little email-button on there with a preset subject and body for the new mail:

```
mailto:?subject=redacted%E2%80%94redacted&body=whatever
```

Actually this should come out as `redacted—redacted` with the mdash correctly in place, which it does when we test this on our systems - everything works fine.

But a client is complaining about it not working in Internet Explorer. It's working fine in Firefox on the same system but Internet Explorer would open up outlook with a subject line prefilled with `redactedâ€”redacted` which is the Windows-1252 interpretation of that UTF-8 character.

The encoding on the page is set to UTF-8 however:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Webserver headers don't specify a different encoding that might confuse the browser:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 14 Dec 2012 08:27:02 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=20
Server:nginx/1.2.2
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Any hints where the problem might be originating from?

Comment: Can you try with the real http header? Btw, that interpretation is in Windows-1252, becasue ISO-8859-1 doesn't have the characters `€` or `”`.

Comment: Have your web server send the charset in a real http header instead of  using meta tag.

Comment: Hmm ok we'll try to see if it works. Main problem here is we can't reproduce the problem so it's pretty hard to test.

Comment: You could use the same IE version as client and explicitly set wrong encoding from the right click context menu in IE and see if that reproduces it. It could also be a problem with the email client the client is using as well?

Comment: Well I still can't reproduce the issue with any browser. Using the same browser set to the wrong encoding will show the encoding wrong on the page but still show it correctly in the mail subject line. We implemented the HTTP headers and we'll see if this has some effect but for the meantime we implemented simple replacements with ascii characters now as those are working...